# Error in Scala Maven recompilation without code change

Tags: scala, maven, scala-maven-plugin

When I check out https://github.com/alexeyr/scala-time and build it once using Maven, everything works fine. Then I touch src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/Implicits.scala to trigger a recompilation. Run `mvn compile` again, and I get 56 errors similar to

```
[ERROR] F:\MyProgramming\scala-time\src\main\scala\org\scala_tools\time\StaticDateTime.scala:29: error: value second is not a member of Int
[ERROR]   def nextSecond = now + 1.second
```

It appears not to see the implicits defined in the touched file and imported with `import org.scala_tools.time.Implicits._`. But at the same time there is no error `object Implicits is not a member of package org.scala_tools.time`, as I would expect to see in this case.

After `mvn clean` it can be compiled once without error again.

1. Can anybody reproduce this?
2. If yes, how can I fix it?

UPDATE: it also happens with SBT, but only if `Implicits.scala` is actually changed enough to produce different class files (e.g. add a line `object Implicits2 extends Implicits`). And the set of errors is different!

Comment: I can recreate - `git clone https://github.com/alexeyr/scala-time.git; cd scala-time; mvn compile ; touch src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/Implicits.scala; mvn compile`.

Comment: Unsatisfying fix: `rm -rf target ; mvn compile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recreate the error without `maven`, so it looks like this might be an issue with how `scalac` is being used (or a bug with `scalac`):

```
% rm -rf target
% mkdir -p target/classes
% cat scalac-args | sed "s;~;$HOME;g" | xargs scalac-2.9 # runs successfully
% cat scalac-args | sed "s;~;$HOME;g" | xargs scalac-2.9
#...
56 errors found
```

(the `sed` command just resolves the `.m2` directory in `scalac-args`)

Where `scalac-args` is

```
-target:jvm-1.5
-classpath
~/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.9.1-1/scala-library-2.9.1-1.jar:~/.m2/repository/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.jar:~/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.1/joda-time-2.1.jar:target/classes
-d
target/classes
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/DurationBuilder.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/Implicits.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/Imports.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichAbstractDateTime.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichAbstractInstant.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichAbstractPartial.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichAbstractReadableInstantFieldProperty.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichChronology.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichDate.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichDateMidnight.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichDateTime.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichDateTimeFormatter.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichDateTimeProperty.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichDateTimeZone.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichDuration.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichInstant.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichInt.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichLocalDate.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichLocalDateProperty.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichLocalDateTime.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichLocalDateTimeProperty.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichLocalTime.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichLocalTimeProperty.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichLong.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichMonthDay.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichMonthDayProperty.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichPartial.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichPartialProperty.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichPeriod.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichReadableDateTime.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichReadableDuration.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichReadableInstant.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichReadableInterval.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichReadablePartial.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichReadablePeriod.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichYearMonth.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/RichYearMonthProperty.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticDateTime.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticDateTimeFormat.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticDateTimeZone.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticDuration.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticInterval.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticLocalDate.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticLocalDateTime.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticLocalTime.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticPartial.scala
src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticPeriod.scala
```

And the proper jars have already been downloaded.

If I replace `target/classes` with `target/classes/org/scala_tools/time/` in the `-classpath` argument, then it works fine then.

```
% rm -rf target
% mkdir -p target/classes
% cat scalac-args | sed "s;~;$HOME;g" | xargs scalac-2.9 # runs successfully
% cat scalac-args | sed "s;~;$HOME;g" | xargs scalac-2.9 # runs successfully
```

So it looks like the `maven-scala-plugin` expects `scalac` to look in package-appropriate subdirectories when given a directory on the path, but `scalac` isn't doing that.  I'm not sure who's wrong.

Comment: Strange. I'll ask on scala-users mailing list and hope they can help. The thing is, if this _is_ a scalac bug, why isn't everyone running into it?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: I don't know - I just got started using `scala`, so I'm not the best source.  Maybe most people use `sbt` instead of `maven`?

Comment: See the update: the problem also exists with `sbt`. It's just smarter about avoiding recompilation.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: I think it's `scalac` then - I've made [a pretty small case that demonstrates the bug](https://github.com/rampion/scalac-compile-bug).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: [Filed a bug report](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5639).

Comment: I've just pushed a fix which will be available in `2.12.0-M1` and in `2.11.5 -Xsource:2.12`.

Answer (score 1):

> Unsatisfying fix: rm -rf target ; mvn compile – rampion 9 hours ago

Useless fix because he can do `mvn clean compile` - and this will be cross-platform solution :)